# Replace command with ^word1^word2 in alias

Tags: command, alias, zshrc

Hello I have a long command like this :

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e password mypassword -e class 'com.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX#testsomething[false]' -e clearPackageData true com.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

And I want to have a command that I can invoke quickly to replace the password.

The following command is perfect when I enter it in the shell but it doesn't work when I create an alias for it like this:

```
alias fastcommandchange="^mypassword^real_password"
```

Any ideas ? or suggestions ? or questions ? (I use zshrc)

Comment: `^mypassword^real_password` is a history substitution, not a command.

Comment: And do you know if it's achievable to put it in a command ?

Comment: I don't think you can put history expansion in a command.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466540/how-can-i-alias-a-history-expansion-in-zsh